# Call Webmethod in jQuery with Parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, webmethod

I have a webMethod that takes on argument from a server session userID session

```
[WebMethod]
    public void getNotificationList(string userID)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(t.std_notification_get_list(int.Parse(userID))));
    }
}
```

I want to call this web method from a jQuery script and populate the data to an HTML tabel

```
<table id="data-table-combine" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-nowrap">Message</th>
                            <th class="text-nowrap">User From</th>
                            <th class="text-nowrap">User To</th>
                            <th class="text-nowrap">Date</th>
                            <th class="text-nowrap">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The script is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    showTableData();

    //$('#submit').click(function () {
    //    showTableData();

    //    var var_name = ('#name');
    //    alert(var_name.valueOf());
    //});
});
var showTableData = function ()
{
    var sValue = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"]%>';
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        method: "post",
        url: 'UserService.asmx/getNotificationList',
        data: JSON.stringify({ userID: sValue }),
        success: function (response) {

            var userTable = $('#data-table-combine tbody');
            userTable.empty();

            $(response).each(function (index, duser) {

                alert("UserID : " + sValue + ", Message: " + duser.Message);

                var var_message = (duser.Message == null) ? '' : duser.Message;
                var var_user_from = (duser.User_From == null) ? '' : duser.User_From;
                var var_user_to = (duser.User_To == null) ? '' : duser.User_To;
                var var_action = (duser.Action == null) ? '' : duser.Action;
                var var_date = (duser.Date == null) ? '' : duser.Date;

                userTable.append('<tr class="gradeA"><td>' +
                    var_Message + '</td><td>' + var_user_from + '</td><td>' + var_user_to +
                    '</td><td>' + var_action + '</td><td>' + var_date + '</td></tr>');
            });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //alert(err);
        }
    });
};
```

And when the script run, the table doesn't contain any values.
So, where is the problem ??
And how i can pass the parameter to the webMethod in jQuery ??

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your `getNotificationList` method and check if the method is called?

Comment: also, fire up Fiddler or similar and inspect the request going from your browser to the server. Are you going to the right place? Sending the expected parameters? UserID is present in the session variables? etc

Comment: Actually, why are you using webmethod? Have you tried [HttpPost] instead?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in getNotificationList and the method is not called

Comment: So, what could be the problem ?

Comment: Open browser’s Developers tools by pressing F12 button and switch to Network tab. Refresh the page and check the request initiated to getNotificationsList method and what response you get back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas to try:

Try adding a slash in front of the url so it looks for the service starting at the root:

```
url: '/UserService.asmx/getNotificationList',
```

Also try adding a contentType:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

---

Edit:

You're using a serializer, so return a string. Make sure your method is ***static***.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getNotificationList(string userID)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return js.Serialize(t.std_notification_get_list(int.Parse(userID))));
}
```

The important thing to know about returning json from a web method is that the response is a wrapper. Your actual data is in an object `d`.

```
$(response.d).each(
```

**But**, you have returned a JSON *string*, so to access the data as an object, you have to reconvert it to an object:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(response.d);
```

*Then* you can do

```
$(myData).each(
```

Depending on how your data is structured you might have to make some adjustments, like `myData[0].duser` or `myData[0].Message`.

Comment: I have updated my answer. P.S. You are passing the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try to use them...

```
data: "{userID:" + JSON.stringify(sValue) + "}",
```

or use different way

Declare them before ajax call

```
var data = { userID: sValue };
var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

use it in ajax

```
data: json_data,
```

Comment: Not sure how `data: JSON.stringify({ userID: sValue })` is different from 
`var data = { userID: sValue };
var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: Check you are getting value from here or not '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"]%>';

Comment: Yes i tried to alert the value and there is a value